# Understanding Conditional Probability with More than 2 Events

Tags: probability

Is there a difference between:

$$p(y|x,z) = \frac{p(y,x|z)}{p(x|z)}$$
and
$$p(y|x,z) = \frac{p(y,x,z)}{p(x,z)}$$

I was working on a problem that asks one to prove $p(x, y|z) = p(x|z)p(y|x, z)$ and the second one just came to my mind.

Comment: Both are correct.  Use which ever you find the most useful.

Comment: Correct as in they would give the same value? Also, can you elaborate/provide a reference related to choosing whichever is the "most useful"? I've noticed that many probabilities can be written in multiple ways.

Comment: Notice that the first *is* what you are trying to prove; so you should not use it to prove itself.

Answer (score 1):

They are both correct; use whichever you find the most useful.
$$\begin{align}\mathsf p(y\mid x, z) ~=~&\dfrac{\mathsf p(x, y\mid z)}{\mathsf p(x\mid z)} \tag 1\\[1ex]~=~&\dfrac{\mathsf p(x,y,z)}{\mathsf p(x, z)}\tag 2\end{align}$$

In this case that is (2), which follows directly from the definition of conditional probability, while (1) *is* what you are trying to prove (and we should aim to avoid circular proofs).

So $$\begin{align}\mathsf p(x,y\mid z) ~=~& \frac{\mathsf p(x,y,z)}{\mathsf p(z)} &\text{definition: conditional probability}\\[1ex]=~& \frac{\mathsf p(x,z)~\mathsf p(y\mid x, z)}{\mathsf p(z)} &\text{definition: conditional probability} \\[1ex] \vdots~& \end{align}$$